# How to make a list of layers in tensorflow like nn.ModuleList

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

How to define a list of layers like `nn.ModuleList` does in pytorch. such that we can use `self.layers[i](A,H)` ; `GTLayer` creates a custom layer.

```
layers = []
for i in range(num_layers):
    layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=False))

self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)

for i in range(self.num_layers):
   H, W = self.layers[i](A, H)
```

**In tensorflow:** how do we define the list of layers? I tried doing it like this using `layers` after appending.

```
layers = []
for i in tf.range(num_layers):
     layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=False))

self.layers = layers

for i in range(self.num_layers):
   H, W = self.layers[i](A, H)
```

Error: We get the following error in this code:

> ValueError
> ----> 5 d.forward(A, X, target_x, target) ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

**Detailed code of above:**

> In Pytorch, we have the following code for method forward of the class
> GTN. I am not able to understand the concept of the attribute
> self.layer in class GTN. I wish to convert this on to Tensorflow
> framework, what shall we implement instead of self.layers in the
> tensorflow code?

```
class GTN(nn.Module):

init....
layers = []
        for i in range(num_layers):
            if i == 0:
                layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=True))
            else:
                layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=False))
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)

def forward(self, A, X, target_x, target):
    A = A.unsqueeze(0).permute(0,3,1,2) 
    Ws = []
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
        if i == 0:
            H, W = self.layers[i](A)
        else:
            H = self.normalization(H)
            H, W = self.layers[i](A, H)
        Ws.append(W)
```

> My try in converting this pytorch script to tensorflow: But I know I
> have mistakenly defined model = tf.keras.models.Sequential() and hence
> the forward method calls for self.layersi is not defined.

```
Anyone knows how to do it correctly?

class GTN(keras.layers.Layer):

inti...

    layers = []
    for i in tf.range(num_layers):
        if i == 0:
            layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=True))
        else:
            layers.append(GTLayer(num_edge, num_channels, first=False))
    
    #self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

def forward(self, A, X, target_x, target):
    #A = A.unsqueeze(0).permute(0,3,1,2) # A = torch.randn(4, 4, 4)
    A = tf.expand_dims(A, 0)
    Ws = []
    
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
        if i == 0:
            H, W = self.layers[i](A) #self.layers = nn.ModuleList(layers)      
        else:
            H = self.normalization(H)
            H, W = self.layers[i](A, H)
        Ws.append(W)
```

Comment: You already asked the same question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838701/how-to-create-layers-like-pytorchs-nn-modulelist-in-tensorflow why are you asking again? Only ask questions once.

Comment: I forgot to delete that question! This looks more specific and precise! I wish to retain this question and delete the previous one! Sorry for this mistake!

Comment: Then delete the previous one, and in any case, there is no need to create new questions since you can always edit your own questions.